# AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python

I had already installed Sci-kit Learn, Numpy, Pandas and Sklearn but I'm getting this error when I run my script in Pycharm. How to fix this? What do all these errors mean?

The message that I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 2, in <module>
import pandas as pd
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", 
line 55, in <module>
from pandas.core.api import (
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", 
line 24, in <module>
from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (  # noqa: F401
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 44, in <module>
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 115, in <module>
from pandas.core.series import Series
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 84, in <module>
import pandas.plotting
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\plotting\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
from pandas.plotting._core import (
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 17, in <module>
import pandas.plotting._matplotlib  # noqa
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from pandas.plotting._matplotlib.boxplot import (
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\boxplot.py", line 4, in <module>
from matplotlib.artist import setp
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
from . import cbook, rcsetup
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 28, in <module>
from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py", line 15, in <module>
from pyparsing import (Literal, ZeroOrMore, Optional, Regex, StringEnd,
File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pyparsing\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
__version__ = __version_info__.__version__
AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__version__` attribute is not part of the `__version_info__` object.  If you are attempting to concatenate a version string do the following:

instead of:

```py
__version__ = __version_info__.__version__
```

try:

```py
__version__ = f'{__version_info__}.{__version__}'
```